# Can I detect whether my roaming data will actually roam?

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, roaming

I'm writing a C#/XAML Metro app, and plan to have my app put some data in roaming storage.

From what I understand, roaming storage will [automatically roam to the user's other devices via the cloud](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh464917.aspx) if:

- the user is signed into Windows using a Live ID (not a plain old local user), and
- roaming has not been disabled by group policy.

Is there some API where I can detect whether roaming data will *actually* roam, or not? I'd love to include a little callout in my app saying "this data will be available from your other devices" -- and, more importantly, "this data [will be lost if you don't use the app for 30 days](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh464917.aspx)" -- and leave off those details if they're using a plain old local user, or if roaming is disabled.

Comment: Haven't seen it.  I seriously doubt it exists, promising roaming and then it not actually working because of some flaky server or connectivity problem would generate some *really* irate customer service calls.  The kind you wouldn't want to answer either :)